# Expressing "should do" with こと・べき・もの

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> 上手{じょうず} に なりたければ もっと 練習{れんしゅう} する **[こと/べき/もの]** だ

As per my understanding, all the 3 options seem appropriate above.
Is that correct?
If so, are there any quirks or exceptions?

Comment: Related: [Difference between sentence final ものだ and ことだ](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6372/542)

Answer (score 3):

They all work.  None are particularly conversational though, so usage differs.  することだ is quite strong, so you would use it sparingly.  In fact, I'd say for the first two, a better translation is "you must..."

For "should do...",  I'd recommend looking up:

するほうがいい/したほうがいい
しなければなりません/しないといけない

Comment: These are much better alternatives in spoken Japanese

Answer (score 1):

こと to support a rule or a culturally-held-wisdom that says "Look both ways before crossing the street" or whatever

べき Kinda oldschool.  Also interchangeable with Beshi if you go way back in time.  It's more like "The governing bodies [should] take care of the poor" or something to that degree.  It's usually used for law or community-based action.

もの Not really the first that comes to mind when using "should" or "in order for things to go well" ... but it's usable.  I think that *mono* is more for "Hey if you wanna succeed, you're gonna have to study hard, it's just one of those things." ... that sort of feel will probably not steer you wrongly.

Hope that helps.  Please excuse the romaji, but to me Romaji are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Vたほうがいい is pretty commonly used as "should." In Japan I have almost never heard べき from a Japanese speaker. However ほうがいい expresses "should" in the sense of something imperative, but is slightly weaker in the sense of suggestion though it is suggestive, in which case sometimes たらいい is better.

The situations I'm talking about are like this:

> You should probably get a license.
> 免許あったほうがいいと思う
>
> You should go to the party!
> パーティいったらいい！